# How to bind oracle params in scala?

Tags: oracle, scala

i have done of code that it executes any query in scala it works perfect unless if my query has to use same parameter twice. the database version is 12 and the oracle jar is ojdbc6, i wrote this code in order to execute query

```
def executeQuery(locale: String, query: String, input: Map[String, String], output: List[String]): Vector[Map[String, Any]] = {
    var connection: Connection = null;
    val properties = ConnectionLoader.getConnectionProperties(locale);
    try {
      connection = getDBConnection(properties);
      val statement = connection prepareCall (query)
      if (null != input)
        for ((k, v) <- input) {
          statement.setObject(k, v)
        }

      for (k <- output) {
        statement.registerOutParameter(k, OracleTypes.INTEGER)
      }
      val resultSet = statement.executeQuery();


      realize(resultSet);
    } catch {
      case e => throw e;
    } finally {
      if (null != connection)
        connection.close();
    }
  }
```

and my query is

```
SELECT COUNT (1) 
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE ORDER_ID = :P_ORDER_ID  AND STATUS_ID = 4
```

this query works fine but im getting an error when executing

```
SELECT COUNT (1)
  FROM ORDERS
 WHERE ORDER_ID = :P_ORDER_ID  AND STATUS_ID = 4 and :P_ORDER_ID=9
```

Regardless to this unlogical query i'm getting this error

**Execution exception[[SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2]]**
i have googled everything but i got no result please advise

Comment: Please, show us also the parameters you pass to your `executeQuery` when you get this error. Does your query really contain `and :P_ORDER_ID=9` part? If so, this is a mistake, you should pass parameters value as a part of `input`

Comment: @SergGr thanks for your response, for sure im sending the parameters throw input map and it i'm completely sure that the parameter is getting binding one time and the second one getting miss

Comment: Basil, still can you show us exact parameters you pass?

Comment: Sure  `DB.executeQuery(locale, scala.io.Source.fromFile(SQL.getOrderStatusHistoryCount, SQL.encoding).
      getLines.mkString, Map("P_ORDER_ID" -> orderId.toString), Nil)`

Comment: Basil, what I asked for is exact `String` text of the `query`. But what you've shown is just how you load it from somewhere. Also it makes sense to update question with such details rather than just put them into comments. The main question text supports new lines :).

Comment: @SergGr thank you for your response but actually this is the exact Query :D 
i'm loading it from sql files

Comment: Basil, it looks like I misread your question altogether.

Comment: It's okay thank you for your time

Comment: Basil, sorry for you time spent so wrongly. Still just in case, could you add which version of Oracle and their JDBC drivers you use. Also stack trace might be helpful.

Comment: No problem i really appreciate that you are trying to help me, pleaes check my updated answer